# How can I smooth the edges of a bitmap (png) in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to remove the background from the image but the edges were jagged. Help me I need to add the smooth effect to the final bitmap.

Comment: Can you not just blur the image? Will that not smooth out the edges?

Comment: How did you remove the background

Comment: The answer will depend on that